# How to browse through a 2d array using one operator only ? no pointers

Tags: arrays, for-loop, 2d

I need to browse through a 2D array and print only the positive numbers.
But, it's contingent on me using just one parameter since a 2D array is only one line basically.
Help is much appriciated!

```
int Positive(double A[SIZE][SIZE], int size) {//The method will recieve a 2D array and return the amount of positive numbers inside.
//Declaring variables.
    int i = 0, positive = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < (size*size);i++)
    {
        if (A[i] > 0)
            positive++;
    }
    return positive;//TThe amount of positive numbers inside the 2D array.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int Positive(double A[][SIZE], int size){
int i, j;
int positive = 0;
for ( i =0; i < size; i++){
    for ( j = 0; j < size; j++){
        if ( A[i][j] > 0 ){
            positive++;
        }
    }
}
return positive;
```

}

Hope this is what you are looking for.